# Convert java sql date format to another format

Tags: java, sql

I have a date retrieved from a sql database (example : 2013-08-22 00:00:00.000). I need to convert this to another format (example: Aug-2013).

> 2013-08-22 00:00:00.000 -> Aug-2013

How do I do this using java?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (If you wish to format the date the way you want):

Suppose the String variable containing the date is "date"...

```
String[] months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
int index = date.subString(5,6);
String year = date.subString(0,3);
date = months[index-1] + "-" + year;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your date is retrieved from the database, then you should retrieve it using `.getDate` method of the `ResultSet`. That way you're getting a proper `Date` object, which you can format any way you like.

If it comes from elsewhere as a string, then you can create a `SimpleDateFormat` object with the specific format you need and use `parse` method to get the `Date` object.  Then, again, you can format it any way you like.

Comment: It works. I used "new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yy");". Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Get the number of seconds since a date in the past such as January 1st 1970.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(s,'1970-01-01','2013-08-22') AS seconds
```

Then you can take this value and add it to the same date in Java, or any other language for that matter.

This will be a reliable way to get around regional differences in date formats.